# Matlab Simulink slprj vs sfprj with reference models

Tags: compilation, simulink, mex

Could anyone explain the difference between the content of the compiled files in slprj and sfprj folders? Basically what is the main intent of these directories? And what is the connection between slprj and sfprj folders and Reference Models, S-Functions and MEX files ?

Answer (score 0):

When simulated, many blocks (such as the `MATLAB Function Block` and a `Stateflow Chart`) are automatically converted to C-code and compiled into an S-Function.  It is the S-function that is run in the simulation.  That all happens somewhat opaquely to the user.

The `slprj` directory (or more specifically the sub folders under it) contain the remnants of that conversion, and the files/data/etc required to run the block correctly during simulation.

Until very recently the directory was named `sfprj`.

The directory was first introduced with the introduction of Stateflow - hence the name `sfprj`.
Since then, more and more functionality (e.g. `MATLAB Function` and `Model Reference` blocks) have made use of the same directory, so recently it was renamed to `slprj` to reflect that it is now used by Simulink in general and not just Stateflow.